# Download file from presigned url minio

Tags: node.js, file, http, https, minio

I have a presigned url from minio which contains a pdf file. The url is valid for 24 hours. How to download the file from the url without saving into local or server and send the file as an attachment to nodemailer.

```
https.get(signedUrl)
     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sample.pdf'))
     .on('finish', function () {
      console.log('Downloaded!!');
  });
```

I tried this code but the file is getting save to local. Is there any way to download it without saving to local or server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using `http` and `nodemailer`

```
https.get(signedUrl, res => {
  transporter.sendMail({
    ..., // Other params
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: 'example.pdf',
        content: res,
      }
    ]
  });
})
```

If it's an array, we have to build a attachments array:

```
const promises = []
const attachments = [];

for (const url of signedUrl) {
  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(url, res => {
      attachments.push({
        filename: 'example.pdf',
        content: res,
      })
      resolve();
    })
  }))
}

await Promise.all(promises);

transporter.sendMail({
  ..., // Other params
  attachments
});
```

Comment: If the signedurl is an array of elements and attachments are not directly in the transporter . How to add the attachments as the array? 
 const mailOptions = {
                from:
                to: 
                attachments: attachment
            }

Comment: this is not working. Mail is not sent but its not throwing any error too. Nodemailer hangs on sending mail.

Comment: Use `transporter.sendMail().catch(e => console.log(e))` to log error. If no error means files are still downloading.

Comment: This is working. thank you!! Can we make the filenames dynamic. 
for (var itr of reports) {
                let signedUrl = (await minio.getSignedUrl("bucketname", "folder", itr));
                promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    http.get(signedUrl, res => {
                        attachment.push({
                            filename: itr,
                            content: res,
                        })
                        resolve(" ");
                    })
                }))
            }
Its picking the last filename for all files

Comment: For short: use `for (const itr of reports)` instead of `var itr`. Please read more about var, let, const in javascript.